# How to lock adding and deleting entire rows and columns in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, worksheet

In my code, an Excel application is created as well as a workbook in it and a worksheet in the workbook. How can I lock now the possibility to add and delete entire rows and columns in the worksheet in order to not allow to an Excel user to perform these operations (all corresponding items in the context menus of Excel have to be disabled)?

Probably, this task can be solved with a proper use of the `Protect` method of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet` interface. However, I do not know exactly how to apply this method correctly. Any suggestions? Or some other way?

Comment: have you looked [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.protect.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)? The AllowDeletingColumns/AllowDeletingRows is the important part for you...

Comment: Nice. But I need an example how to use these parameters.

Comment: Like `((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet).Protect(getPasswordFromUser, true)` for [vsto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkcs53f3.aspx)?